# How to ungetc a whole string in c?

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, c-strings

My proposed solution I get an error in a different part of my code so im skeptical if it works.

````
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (int i = len-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        ungetc(str[i],file);
    }
    return;
}```
````

Comment: You can't. `ungetc` only allows for one character to be pushed back to the stream. Anything else is implementation-defined.

Comment: In any case `i > 0` does not iterate the *whole* string, you need `i >= 0`

Comment: As per comments about, ungets is limited to 1 character. `fseek` may introduce other problems. What is the problem that you are trying to solve  ?. Are you trying to 'undo' a scanf ? Can you share the reason/context